# How to find the number of checkboxes in all pages of a datatable jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, datatable

How to find the number of checkboxes in all pages of a datatable jquery plugin

Comment: How does your table look like? I.e the markup and how you initialise the dataTable.

Answer (score 0):

`$('input:checkbox').length;`

Using the selector `:checkbox` you can find all the box and getting their number you can use `.length`.

`$('input.checkboxclass').length;`

Another one is using a class. Add a `class` to all your checkbox then using that class as selector you can get all the checkbox and use it to get the `.length`.

Comment: this one is used get the number of checkbox in a page of the datatable.
But i want to count number of check boxes in the all pages of a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function (){    
    $("#viewcat").DataTable({
      "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){               
               $("td:nth-child(2)", nRow).append(aData[7]);
               return nRow;
            },
      "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ){
              var len = $('input.classname').length;
              alert(len);
            },      
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true,
      "order": [ 2, "asc" ],
      "aoColumnDefs": [ { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0, 1, 4, 5 ,6] } ],
      "ajax":{
          url :"ajax_page.php", // json datasource
          type: "post",        
          error: function(){  
          $(".viewcat-error").html("");
          $("#viewcat").append('<tbody class="viewcat-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server</th></tr></tbody>');
          $("#viewcat_processing").css("display","none");          
          }
      }
    });

  });
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Explanation : Let focus on the event 'fnDrawCallback' ,inside that we can put whatever front end code we needed and it will be effective after calling a particular table as datatable..let try